# Executing system.schedule scheduled class (Method does not exist or incorrect signature)

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I'm trying to write a scheduler Apex class to create an Accounting Period every month and am getting an error when compiling

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule(String,
>   String, AccountingPeriodCreationService) from the type System

**AccountingPeriodCreationService.cls**

```
public with sharing class AccountingPeriodCreationService  {

public static List <AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c> accountingPeriod;
public static Date currentDate;
public static Date firstDayOfCurrentMonth;
public static Date lastDayOfCurrentMonth;

public void createdAPLogic(){
    accountingPeriod = new List <AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c>();
    currentDate = Date.today();
    firstDayOfCurrentMonth = currentDate.toStartofMonth();
    lastDayOfCurrentMonth = currentDate.addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);


    List<AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c> checkAccountingPeriodAlreadyExist = [SELECT Id, AcctSeed__Start_Date__c, AcctSeed__End_Date__c FROM AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c where AcctSeed__Start_Date__c = :firstDayOfCurrentMonth];

        if(checkAccountingPeriodAlreadyExist.isEmpty()){
            accountingPeriod.add(
                new AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c(
                Name = 'Name',
                AcctSeed__Status__c = 'Status',
                AcctSeed__Start_Date__c = firstDayOfCurrentMonth,
                AcctSeed__End_Date__c = lastDayOfCurrentMonth
                )
            );
        }
   } 
}
```

**CreateAccountingPeriods.cls**

```
global with sharing class CreateAccountingPeriods implements Schedulable {
/**
 * @description Executes the scheduled Apex job. 
 * @param sc contains the job ID
 */ 

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    //Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context
     AccountingPeriodCreationService apc = new AccountingPeriodCreationService();
    String sch = '0 1 0 1 1/1 ? *';
    String jobID = system.schedule('Create Accounting Period', sch, apc);
   }


}
```

With the line below marked up

**String jobID = system.schedule('Create Accounting Period', sch, apc);**

I've spent the past few hours trying to figure out why the error is there and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateAccountingPeriods` is your scheduled job. You don't need to schedule again. Instead, just call the appropriate method from your `AccountingPeriodCreationService` class:

```
global with sharing class CreateAccountingPeriods implements Schedulable {
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    new AccountingPeriodCreationService().createdAPLogic();
  }
}
```

---

P.S. it looks like you could just make the method static, too, which would simplify your code:

```
public static void createdAPLogic() { //...
```

---

```
global with sharing class CreateAccountingPeriods implements Schedulable {
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    AccountingPeriodCreationService.createdAPLogic();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to schedule the class, that can't be scheduled. To schedule a class, it has implements Schedulable interface. So, in your particular case, `CreateAccountingPeriods` has to be scheduled not the `AccountingPeriodCreationService`.

Try to invoke  `createdAPLogic` from `CreateAccountingPeriods` and then schedule the last via "execute anon. windows".

---

Oh, and there is something else. You are adding `AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c` record to list, but it will never be inserted as you are not calling `insert` operator

Answer (score 0):

create new class to make AccountingPeriodCreationService as scheduler.

```
  global class AccountingPeriodCreationServiceScheduler implements Schedulable {
        global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) { 
           new AccountingPeriodCreationService().createdAPLogic();
        }    
    }
```

You can use this scheduler class in apex scheduler to schedule at particular time.

You can test AccountingPeriodCreationServiceScheduler using test class like below.

```
 @istest
public class AccountingPeriodCreationServiceSchedulerTest {
    @istest

    public static void  testschedule() {

        Test.StartTest();
        AccountingPeriodCreationServiceScheduler sh1 = new AccountingPeriodCreationServiceScheduler();      
         String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?';
                system.schedule('Test check', sch, sh1);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Scheduling CreateAccountingPeriods will result in errors, because every time past the first it will try to schedule a job that does not have a unique name.

Comment: What is error? Can you please post here?

Comment: CreateAccountingPeriods is redundant, because all it does is create a new job. However, since the first parameter is a fixed string, this will result in the scheduled job failing every time past the first that it runs. The Scheduler class you presented by itself would be fine.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. You are right. I have updated it.